# Can the AT-D878UV be programmed for dPMR channels?

Tags: dmr, anytone

I am curious whether the Anytone AT-D878UV (which is a DMR radio) can be programmed to receive dPMR channels.

I understand that the big difference between DMR and dPMR is the technique used to divide the  12.5kHz channels into 2 6.25kHz sub-channels: DMR uses TDMA (time division) while dPMR uses FDMA (frequency division).

Is there a way to switch the radio to FDMA? Would it be enough to support dPMR channels?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to believe that using dual time slots (DCDM) mode might work with dPMR, since you are no longer bothering with TDMA. However, I couldn't find anything in my research. Try switching the AT-D878UV to use both time slots at the same time and test it with a dPMR radio on simplex. While it probably won't work, it's your best bet since DCDM does not rely on time synchronization, so it may just be a rebranded dPMR mode for simplex.